# ASP.NET HiddenField Value Setting

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have googled this, but can't figure out how to set the value of my hidden field.  I have the following code:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="fileId" runat="server" value="<%# Response.Write(Request.QueryString["fileID"]) %>" />
```

I am just trying to make the value = the value of `fileID` in the query string.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From the code-behind: `fileId.Value = Request.QueryString["fileID"];`

Comment: Thanks, that is a solution, too.  I wanted to figure it out inline, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
<asp:HiddenField id="fileId" runat="server" value='<%= Request.QueryString["fileID"] %>' />
```

Believe the "=" operator implies the Response.Write for you.

Just for the sake of completeness, you could set it in the codebehind as well, eg

```
fileId.Value = Request.QueryString["fileID"]
```

Comment: I didn't use the `=` operator, but I did change from my double quotes to using single quotes and it works...  Didn't realize I couldn't use single quotes here.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Your photo is making me so hungry!  It's lunch time where I am